# Append to sub-element later

Tags: python, lxml

I'm building an xml with lxml.builder in Python, but I want to locate sub-elements with an attribute later due to the nature of my code. Then I want to add a sub-element to that. The XML will contain hashes of files and their size and filename.

I looked at the lxml documentation, but I couldn't find a function that does what I want.

```py
base = etree.Element("datafile")
header = etree.Element("header")
for f in ["name", "description", "version", "author", "comment"]:
    header_var = etree.Element(f)
    if f == "category":
        header_var.text = "Standard DatFile"
    else:
        header_var.text = "-insert {}-".format(f)
    header.append(header_var)
base.append(header)

game = lb.E.game(
       lb.E.rom(name=f, size=size, crc=hash_crc32, md5=hash_md5, sha1=hash_sha1), name=filename1)
base.append(game)
```

After I append the `game` element to the XML, I want to access it again later by looking up the element using the `game` tag and the `name` attribute, and adding another sub-element with `rom` inside it. It runs in a loop, so that's why I would want to append to the XML first. (otherwise, I'd probably have to make a dictionary to temporarily store the data before it's inserted).

It would be nice to make sure the tag with the attribute exists first too (not sure how to do that).

EDIT: I cleaned it up. It ignores the attribute in the xpath though. I need help to make it stop ignoring it.

```py
base = etree.Element("datafile")
header = etree.SubElement(base, "header")
for f in ["name", "description", "version", "author", "comment"]:
    header_var = etree.SubElement(header, f)
    if f == "category":
        header_var.text = "Standard DatFile"
    else:
        header_var.text = "-insert {}-".format(f)

try:
        path = etree.xpath(base, "game", name=filename1)[0]
        etree.SubElement(path, "rom", name=f, size=size, crc=hash_crc32, md5=hash_md5, sha1=hash_sha1)
except:
        game = etree.SubElement(base, "game", name=filename1)
        game.SubElement(game, "rom", name=f, size=size, crc=hash_crc32, md5=hash_md5, sha1=hash_sha1)
```

Comment: You can use [XPath](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)

Comment: It's possible, but this makes only sense if you have **only one** `game` `tag`.

Comment: @Larsenv: Your **first** approach is correct. Do you want to append more than **one** `<game ...`?

Answer (score 0):

An XPath would use `game[@name = $filename]` and in lxml I think instead of `path = etree.xpath(base, "game", name=filename1)[0]` you want `path = base.xpath('game[@name = $filename]', filename=filename1)[0]`.